# Which methods are dynamically bound in Java?

Tags: java, dynamic-binding

What the question says, which methods are dynamically bound in Java?

Coming from C++, if I am not mistaken, most methods are statically bound with a few exceptions.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/dynamic-binding-vs-static-binding-in.html

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/properties/bound.html http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/bound.html

Comment: Java non static methods are virtual by default. The jit optimises the code to minimise the overhead associated with doing this. Eg it can inline virtual methods.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, all methods are dynamically bound, with the exception of

- Static methods
- Constructors
- Private methods
- Final methods

In practice, at runtime the JVM may choose to JIT-compile some method calls to be statically resolved, for instance if there are no loaded classes containing an overriding method.

Comment: Methods marked private and final in the parent class are statically bound too

Answer (score 3):

Instance method calls are resolved at runtime, static method calls are resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can think of it like thie:
At compile time the compiler checks the static binding.
At runtime the dinamic type is checked.

for Example:

```
Class A{
  public void function x(){ print("x"); }
}
Class B extends A{
  public void function x(){ print("y"); }
  public void function m(){ print("m"); }
}

public static void main(){
   A a = new B();
   a.x();        //1
   a.m();        //2
   ((B)a).m();   //3
}
```

- in 1 will compile because the static type of a is A and A has a function called X, but at runtime there will be recognized a B object, and printed 'y'
- in 2 there will be a compilation error because a is of type A and the class A has no function called m.
- in 3 there will be checked if that inheritance B->A is legal, and then if class B has an function called m.

*notice that in the last case of casting, the compiler checks only the possibility of inheritance and not that there will be a B object.
for example:

```
A a = new A();
((B)a).m();
```

will compile but throw a runntime exception.